What is Kibble?
In the Expanse, they mention "Kibble" several times as a foodstuff eaten on the belt.
Red Kibble is supposed to be spicy, and white kibble is mentioned as well.
Is there anything in canon (TV show or books) to say what kibble actually is?

No copy and paste?

@AaarghZombies You are allowed to answer your own question.

Note it's a standard term (in the UK, at least) for dried pet food, so you can infer the Expanse version is something similar.

In the Expanse universe 'Kibble' is a proteinous food with added salt and/or spices. The protein source for the 'white' variety appears to be mushroom and (kidney?) beans for the 'red' variety.
As far as presentation is concerned, it can be fried into balls, desiccated and crumbled, compressed into flat protein bars or impasted.

Notable ingredients
Beans

The meal was the heavily spiced and deep-fried balls of bean paste
that Belters called red kibble.
Persepolis Rising

Mushroom (white kibble)

Then she pulled on a fresh jumpsuit, went to the galley, made herself
a bowl of white kibble, and sat. A message was waiting for her from
Bobbie, and she set her hand terminal on the table when she played it
so she could use both hands to eat. The kibble was warm and peppery;
the mushroom squeaked against her teeth just the way it was supposed
to.
Persepolis Rising

Mushroom (and possibly cheese powder?)

Salis sat in an open-air bar with Vandercaust and Roberts, drinking beer and eating white kibble that tasted of cheese powder and mushroom.
Babylon's Ashes

Salt

“I got you white kibble and lemonade. Salt, sugar, and water. I
figured, you know, electrolytes.”
Leviathan Falls

Since lemonade doesn't contain large amounts of salt, it stands to reason that this is to be found in the kibble.
Ground up protein

These people were what it was all about, Miller told himself. Normal
people living small lives in a bubble of rock surrounded by hard
vacuum. If they let the station turn into a riot zone, let order fail,
all these lives would get turned into kibble like a kitten in a meat
grinder. Making sure it didn’t happen was for people like him, Muss,
even Shaddid.
Leviathan Wakes

I think we can assume that kibble isn't literally made of kitten meat since Belter life is (largely) vegan.
Cumin (Red Kibble)

She opted for red kibble from a scarred kiosk with adhesive from
generations of nightclub flyers caking its sides. It came in a brown
pressed-shred container that fit in her left palm with a plastic
spatula like a flattened spoon to eat with. The first bite filled her
mouth with cumin and her mind with dust-covered memory.
Nemesis Games

Bean sprouts (found in fancy white kibble)

The restaurant did a good Belt/Mars fusion menu. Something called
white kibble that was related to the real thing, but with fresh
vegetables and bean sprouts.
Tiamat's Wrath

'Vegetables'

The food wasn’t bad. Vat-grown ribs in a hot marinade and vegetable
kibble that hadn’t been cooked to a mush.
Tiamat's Wrath


Out-of-universe 'kibble' is a generic term for compound feed which is where it seems to derive its name in-universe.

Compound feed is fodder that is blended from various raw materials and
additives. These blends are formulated according to the specific
requirements of the target animal. They are manufactured by feed
compounders as meal type, pellets or crumbles. The main ingredients
used in commercially prepared feed are the feed grains, which include
corn, soybeans, sorghum, oats, and barley.

